# Use the same source set but not the same AndroidManifest.xml in andorid gradle build

Tags: android, build, gradle

I use product flavors with gradle to build different versions of my app. But I just need to replace some metadata in the AndroidManifest.xml for each version. The source code and resources are all the same.

Everytime, gradle will compile, package, and use proguard to compress the classes for each version independently, but all those things are the same for me. I am wondering is there a way to reduce the time, reuse all that stuff built for both versions, and just change the AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible! You can have different Manifest files in folders named same as your product flavours under the `src` folder.

For example, do this in your gradle:

```
android {
  productFlavors {
    prod {
    }
    dev {
    }
  }
}
```

add a manifest file to `src/dev/`

add another manifest file to `src/prod/`